# Using the back icon from the actionbar

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I am using a custom layout for my actionbar, but would still like to use the standard back-icon of the actionbar (android:homeAsUpIndicator) (it should be displayed or hidden dynamically).

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

My custom layout for the actionbar:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_actionbar_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_actionbar_abort"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@string/button_abort"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="ActionBarTitle"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/actionBarTextviewTitle"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: have you tried to use it?

Comment: @blackbelt I added my current layout of my actionbar, I don't know where I could use android:homeAsUpIndicator?

Comment: Where do you want to show it? Where do you want to hide it? Are you using fragments? We need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in onCreate() method:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```